# VBA Save worksheets with array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a code that will save the specified worksheets into a new workbook. The issue I'm having is it ignores a chart I would like to save. If I put "Figure 1" (the name of the chart) to the array list I get an error: "Subscript out of range". If I change "Figure 1" to the actual name on of the chart I get the same error.

I'm assuming Worksheets(Array(A,B,C)).Copy isn't the code I'm looking for.

Any ideas to copy over the chart?

```
Sub SavSheets()
 Dim InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String

fileSaveName = "C:\Desktop\"
Worksheets(Array("Table 1", "Table 2", "Figure 1", "Table 3")).Copy
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
With wbNew
    .SaveAs fileSaveName
    .Close
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Worksheets` to `Sheets`.

```
Sheets(Array("Table 1", "Table 2", "Figure 1", "Table 3")).Copy
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew it was something simple